# Unable to run a systemd service daemon on Ubuntu (how to switch to Upstart or is there an updated distro)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, systemd, daemons

> Note: I don't have any real experience managing servers or using Linux on any deep level so my knowledge and understanding is quite limited. In essence, I'm winging it.
>
> For full code examples see: https://github.com/Integralist/Vagrant-Examples/tree/master/nodejs

---

This is a two part issue:

1. not being able to mount my shared directory
2. `systemd` services not being available

---

I'm trying to create a service that starts up a NodeJS application but it looks like `systemctl` isn't available on the version of Ubuntu I've installed (https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64).

Here is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Working arround the "stdin: is not a tty" error, which appears when provisioning
  # config.ssh.pty = true

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 3000, auto_correct: true

  # We use Vagrant to create the new "web" group/owner for us
  # But we could have done this manually as part of our provisioning script
  #
  # useradd -mrU web
  # chown web /var/www
  # chgrp web /var/www
  # cd /var/www/
  # su web
  # git clone {code}
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", create: true, group: "web", owner: "web"

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "provision/setup.sh"
  end
end
```

Below is the content of my `setup.sh` provisioning script which creates the `.service` file:

```
su root

mkdir -p /var/www

cat << 'EOF' > /etc/systemd/system/our-node-app.service
  [Service]
  WorkingDirectory=/var/www
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs boot.js
  ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
  Restart=always
  StandardOutput=syslog
  StandardError=syslog
  SyslogIdentifier=some-identifier-here-typically-matching-workingdirectory
  User=web
  Group=web
  Environment='NODE_ENV=production'

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

But when I run a `vagrant up` I get the following error output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: nodejs_default_1407743897168_39018
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 3000 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => /Users/markmcdonnell/Box Sync/Library/Vagrant/nodejs

Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u web`,gid=`getent group web | cut -d: -f3` var_www /var/www
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u web`,gid=`id -g web` var_www /var/www
```

So my first problem is that I can't seem to mount my shared folder.

Also, originally in my provisioning script (after creating the `our-node-app.service` file) I would have the following:

```
systemctl enable our-node-app
systemctl start our-node-app
systemctl status our-node-app
journalctl -u node-sample # logs
```

If I add that back into my provisioning script and then run `vagrant provision --provision-with shell` I'll get the following output:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/n0/jlvkmj5n36vc0932b_1t0kxh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20140811-58128-fa27fk.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 25: systemctl: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 26: systemctl: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 27: systemctl: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 28: journalctl: command not found
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 25: systemctl: command not found
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 26: systemctl: command not found
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 27: systemctl: command not found
/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 28: journalctl: command not found
```

This is where I discovered the issue with the `systemctl` command not being available.

I also tried modifying the provisioning script so that instead of...

```
systemctl enable our-node-app
systemctl start our-node-app
systemctl status our-node-app
journalctl -u node-sample # logs
```

...I would use...

```
service our-node-app start
service --status-all | grep 'node'
```

This was because I had read somewhere that Ubuntu doesn't support `systemd` and instead uses something called `upstart` to boot all its services. I assumed at the time that I could just use the other command and keep the script itself the same (it seems that is not the case).

But all that change did was demonstrate that my service wasn't recognised:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/n0/jlvkmj5n36vc0932b_1t0kxh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20140811-58428-iot9kx.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: our-node-app: unrecognized service
==> default:  [ ? ]  apport
==> default:  [ ? ]  console-setup
==> default:  [ ? ]  cryptdisks
==> default:  [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
==> default:  [ ? ]  dns-clean
==> default:  [ ? ]  irqbalance
==> default:  [ ? ]  killprocs
==> default:  [ ? ]  kmod
==> default:  [ ? ]  networking
==> default:  [ ? ]  ondemand
==> default:  [ ? ]  open-vm-tools
==> default:  [ ? ]  pppd-dns
==> default:  [ ? ]  rc.local
==> default:  [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
==> default:  [ ? ]  sendsigs
==> default:  [ ? ]  umountfs
==> default:  [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
==> default:  [ ? ]  umountroot
==> default:  [ ? ]  virtualbox-guest-x11
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
our-node-app: unrecognized service
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  open-vm-tools
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ ? ]  virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I then discovered that [Ubuntu is going to move](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316) to the `systemd` format after all:  but this was announced back in February 2014 and so I would have thought the latest Ubuntu to have switched over by now (or is that just me being an idiot and not appreciating how long a change like that can take).

Thinking I would have to use this Upstart format, I had started to read through [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) but sadly I wasn't able to work out how to convert my `systemd` script into Upstart's format.

---

This leaves me with the question: has anyone else here had this problem, and if so how did they resolve it (did you switch to a different Ubuntu release that supports `systemd` or rewrite your service to use the Upstart format)?

Do you have any advice (or good resources) on how to convert a `systemd` script over to the Upstart format?

Any help on this subject would be appreciated; as I mentioned at the start, I'm not a system/server op guy and so I'm winging it here.

Thanks.

### Update

I found [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd) and it seems I misunderstood the difference between `systemd`, `init.d` and `upstart`. So `systemd` is a brand new system that improves upon `init.d` and `upstart`.

The article linked to explains how to install `systemd` alongside `upstart` and then switch to `systemd`, but I'm still getting an error trying to mount the VM?

I've updated my [repo](https://github.com/Integralist/Vagrant-Examples/blob/master/nodejs/provision/setup.sh) code.

Comment: The here document needs to be quoted, like `<<'EOF'` (notice the single quotes), otherwise the shell will substitute e.g. `$MAINPID` with its value (which is presumably the empty string at the time the code is executed).

Comment: @tripleee thanks for that info, I'll update accordingly